# Aurelia-router router.navigation does not refresh when a route property is updated

Tags: aurelia

The `nav` property of my `create-team` route is set by an observable property in my `userService`. 
I have one problem though. There is no way to refresh the `router.navigation` array to reflect that my property `isTeamMember` has changed. So even if my `isTeamMember` property returns true then the route would not be hidden unless I do a full page refresh.

I tried with `router.refreshNavigation()` and it did not work, since from what I understand only routes that are set to `nav: true` will be added to the `router.navigation` array.

I'm currently looping through `router.navigation` array to display my menu for my app. But when the user create a team I would like to hide that route from the menu since the user is now a team owner. I handle access to that route with an `AuthorizeStep` which works but would also like to hide this route dynamically.

app.ts

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
...
    var appRoutes = [
        { route: '/create-team', name:'create-team', moduleId: 'routes/create-team', nav: !this.userService.isTeamMember, title: 'menu.create-team', settings: { auth: { isNotTeamMember: true } } },
    ]
...
}
```

Is there a clean way to refresh the `route.navigation` array so my menu is updated without having to do a full page refresh?

Comment: According to https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/216 you probably have to **manually** tinker with the `router.navigation` array and add/remove the item you want. Something like `let index = this.router.navigation.findIndex(r=>r.name == 'name-you-want-to-remove');this.router.navigation.splice(index,1);`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I wish I could avoid that. Let's see if there's another solution, but thanks for the input!

Comment: The problem is that `!this.userService.isTeamMember` is evaluating a property. You're not databinding to that property, you're just evaluating it when creating the route, it doesn't automatically get changed when the value of that property changes. I like the solution suggested by `zedL`. There are some other options, but the one given isn't bad.

Comment: @AshleyGrant what would be the other options you're talking about?

Comment: Here's one: https://gist.run/?id=ccf908a98978394a7aba359d3a0f0276 the reason we have to jump through these hoops is that Aurelia cannot be made aware of changes made to array items via the indexer (`routes[2] = {..}`. It's a limitation of the language that we can't get that. Proxies give us that ability, but we haven't built that support yet due to Proxy support being fairly new to the browsers (and it cannot be polyfilled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over router.routes with an value converter and update the binding with the signaler.

Her is an example gist.

https://gist.run/?id=f2e02b8caa831776d8571b9c886cfdd4

Comment: You could also just use `if.bind="nav.nav"` on the `li` elements, right ?